# Open Source PHP based secure file download script?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, file-manager

I need a self hosted solution where I as the admin can create client areas (which can be simple folders) where I upload files and secure them with username / pass. A client page will then be automatically generated which the client can access the username / pass and download the files.

It's relatively simple script but I'm having a hard time finding open source solutions which accomplish what I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial could be useful for you as a starting point : [A Secure and Efficient PHP Download Script](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Optimize-File-Downloading-in-PHP/)

If your stuck somewhere in your code stackoverflow.com members will be glad to help you
Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.tutorialchip.com/php-download-file-script/

I don't believe it is open source as such (it's distributed under a GPLv2 licence), but it is free and comes with a fairly comprehensive tutorial.